# format of yt.play playlist for embedding a playlist

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

Writing first chrome extension and I cant figure out how to load a playlist with my YT.Player, my attempts of just having an "array" of video ids does not work.

Sorry if this is an easy question to answer, but I looked through the youtube documention and I cant find any specific examples. Thanks

```
var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1,'playlist':['****']},
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'Dn9Z52D2t90'
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
 player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
   playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1,'playlist':['videoid, videoid, ....']},
   height: '390',
   width: '640',
  videoId: 'Dn9Z52D2t90'
 });
}
```

to add videos individually, would stil be nice to add playlist ids.